# How to provision infrastructure in a local zone using terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

AWS recently introduced local zones (ap-south-1-del-1). I am trying to use the region to deploy an EC2 instance. I have enabled the region and the local zone in my AWS account.

This is my terraform provider file :-

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "ap-south-1-del-1"
}

terraform {
  required_version = "> 0.11"
  required_providers {
    aws = "~> 4.0"
  }
}
```

but i keep running into the following :-

```
 Error: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: error validating provider credentials: 
 error calling sts:GetCallerIdentity: operation error STS: GetCallerIdentity, exceeded maximum 
 number of attempts, 9, https response error StatusCode: 0, RequestID: , request send failed, 
 Post "https://sts.ap-south-1-del-1.amazonaws.com/": dial tcp: lookup sts.ap-south-1-del- 
 1.amazonaws.com: no such host
│
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"],
│   on provider.tf line 1, in provider "aws":
│    1: provider "aws" {
│
╵
```

and this is my EC2 instance for anyone curious. Super basic.

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = "ami-0ef82eeba2c7a0eeb"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags = {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  }
}
```

Has anyone tried it? Is it supported? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not change the provider's region. It is still `ap-south-1`. To create EC2 instance in a LZ, you have to follow [three steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/local-zones/latest/ug/getting-started.html#getting-started-find-local-zone):

1. Enable a Local Zone using [aws_ec2_availability_zone_group](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ec2_availability_zone_group)
2. Create subnet in the LZ enabled uzing [aws_subnet](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/subnet)
3. Create instance in the subnet using [aws_instance](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/instance).

Comment: I see. This makes a lot of sense. I'll try step 2. thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update the provider version for aws to work with new local zones. You can go to official provider page and upgrade the version to a newer version for aws provider